# Using a dataframe to Insert data into a BigQuery column of type JSON, produes error - Unable to determine type for field 'json_col'

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

What we're using (the main points):

- google-cloud-bigquery (3.11.3)
- Python (3.10)
- Pandas (2.0.3)

Challenge:
There is a table that already exists in BigQuery, it was made with Terraform not through Python, which we have to append data to. One of these columns is of the data type JSON.
When trying to insert data into this table using a dataframe and the [load_table_from_dataframe()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe) the following error occurs

> ../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:267: UserWarning: Unable to determine type for field 'json_col'.
> warnings.warn("Unable to determine type for field '{}'.".format(bq_field.name))

This is reproducible, so I've included an example of my approach so that it may help highlight where I could be going wrong.

```
def json_test():
    """Set bq_client before starting"""

    # create dataset if not there already
    try:
        dataset_name = 'jtest1'
        bq_client.create_dataset(dataset_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'dataset error - {e}')
    
    # create table if not there already; supply schema to create table with json column    
    try:
        tbl1 = 'jtest1_tbl'
        schema = [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "description": "id column"
            },
            {
                "name": "json_col",
                "type": "JSON",
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "description": "json column"
            }
        ]        
        bq_client.create_table(bigquery.Table(f'fs-nm-import.{dataset_name}.{tbl1}', schema=schema))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Table error - {e}')
        
    # test sample 
    json_test = {
        "id": "test1",
        "json_col": {
            "name": "test",
            "age": 10
        }
    }
    
    # throw in a jobConfig
    jobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("json_col", "JSON", mode="NULLABLE")            
        ],
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    )
    
    # make dataframe: let's try apply as suggested elsewhere...
    df = pandas.DataFrame(
        [json_test]
    )
    df["json_col"] = df["json_col"].apply(json.dumps)
    
    # attempt the insert..
    bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe (
        dataframe=df,
        destination=f"{PROJECT_ID}.{dataset_name}.{tbl1}",
        project=PROJECT_ID,
        job_config=jobConfig
    )
```

Things Tried:
If the table column type is string, than other than setting the right schema, this inserts, but it's the wrong type. This will lead to other changes we'll have to make with SQL queries, which are likely to be a 'nope'.

[insert_rows_from_dataframe()](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_insert_rows_from_dataframe) works without issues, so maybe this is an option, I'd appreciate if anyone could still inform me why the load_table_from_dataframe() doesn't work though.

As a note; the solution just has to be in Python, I don't think I have to use Pandas, I'm just going off some existing code and answers to questions I've gotten thus far.

if I can offer anymore details or anything else, please let me know and thanks kindly in advance.

Comment: Everything about this screams "nope" to me. The first thing I'd do is write off pandas for this; I'd want to just be working with a nested list of data

Comment: @roganjosh, like using the 'insert_rows()" call? Because when tested I had success, but what I also found was it produces a different set of problems because of using the buffer and taking up to 90 mins to stop write changes from happening to that data. The funny thing is, use of a dataframe isn't just documented by Google, it seems to support other cases I've tested, except inserting into a JSON type column. I'm also looking at loading to one table and transforming into a different table. But still why does this produce the above error I guess, is what I'd like to know.